# Getting to grips with Erlang messages

Tags: erlang

I'm still trying to come to grips with Erlang messages, and while playing around with it, I came up with this case. It seems like it should work, but it just hangs indefinitely.

Can someone who is more used to Erlang please explain what I am doing wrong? And yes, I am aware that I don't even look at what is returned. This is the result of trying to reduce the code to isolate the problem.

```
-module(test).
-export([caller/2]).

callee(V1, V2, From) ->
  From ! {V1, V2}.

caller(V1, V2) ->
  spawn(fun() ->
    callee(V1, V2, self()) end),
  receive
    _ ->
      {V1, V2}
  end.
```

Comment: Try moving the call to `self()` outside the spawned process.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense! Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign the result of `self()` to a variable *outside* the function in the call to `spawn` and then pass in that variable instead of the literal `self()` then the message sent in `callee` will correctly be sent to the process running `caller` (the process waiting on `receive`).

Answer (score 1):

This bit will help you understand where is the problem.

```
1> Self = self(), spawn(fun() -> io:format("Self: ~p, self():~p ~n", [Self, self()]) end).
Self: <0.83.0>, self():<0.85.0> 
<0.85.0>
```